# Two internet connections, same target IP - redirect some ports

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet

I have two internet connections - one LAN and one over GPRS (mobile). I'd like to redirect every outgoung request on port 80 to one connection, and port 21, 22 and some others to the other connection.

In another words - I'd like to use internet browser (Google Chrome or Firefox) on one connection and my FTP/SSH (WinSCP, PuTTY) software on the other connection.

Is that possible?

I have Windows 7.

*edit:*

All remote ports will be on the same machine/IP address.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that.  Windows (and I'm pretty sure every TCP/IP implementation) won't support routing based on port numbers.

Routing occurs on the IP address level.  If you wanted to route connections to different IP's to specific connections you could do that with the `route` command.  Since it's the same remote IP that won't work.

Comment: It is true that windows natively does this, but iptables in most linux based system will allow you to choose which interface to use based on port number.

Answer (score 1):

You may use WinGate Server from http://www.wingate.com/products/wingate/index.php , however it is not free. It allows you to multiplex more than two connections. I am not pretty sure if they allow distributing connections based on port but I remember it allows distributing traffic on different connections. It allows handling ports but not sure that the way you want.